# How to implement function with vector of derived classes as parameter

Tags: templates, vector, implementation, idioms

(Related to a previous [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4273869/464629) I asked). I want to implement a function which can be called only with vectors of related classes as parameter.

For eq

if we have

```
class A;
class B: public A;
class C: public A;
class D

then it should be possible to call function with vector<A*>,vector<B*> or 
vector <C*> but not vector <D*>
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already tried to create a method like

```
void doSomething(std::vector<A*>& things)
{
}
```

and tried do pass

```
std::vector<B*> bList = ...;
doSomething(bList);
```

right?

Why does the compiler complain? Because it would not make sense. Consider that doSomething() tries to do

```
things.push_back(new C());
```

This cannot work as "things" is actually a `std::vector<B*>`. However, if it were `std::vector<A*>`, push_back would work.

So what can we learn from this? What you're trying only makes sense if you only read from the vector, however, vector is not a read-only container.

A simple wrapper shows a possible solution (the wrapper can be adjusted to your needs, of course). However, I have to point out that the use of virtual methods might lead to performance penalties.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

template <class Base>
class AbstractVectorWrapper
{
public:
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual Base* getElementAt(int index) const = 0;
};
template <class Base, class Derived>
class VectorWrapper : public AbstractVectorWrapper<Base>
{
private:
    std::vector<Derived*> m_vector;
public:
    explicit VectorWrapper(std::vector<Derived*> const& vector)
        : m_vector(vector)
    {
    }
    virtual size_t size() const
    {
        return m_vector.size();
    }
    virtual Base* getElementAt(int index) const
    {
        return m_vector[index];
    }
};

void doSomething(AbstractVectorWrapper<A> const& wrapper)
{
    for (size_t i=0;i<wrapper.size();i++)
    {
        A* a = wrapper.getElementAt(i);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<A*> as;
    std::vector<B*> bs;
    doSomething(VectorWrapper<A,B>(bs));
    doSomething(VectorWrapper<A,A>(as));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I knew that it is not possible hence the question :-)

Comment: I said WHY it cannot work, not THAT it can't, hence my answer :-).

Answer (score 1):

Is [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) good enough for you? Consider this code

```
template <class T>
void my_function (std::vector <T*> const &values) {
    // Use features of A* here
}
```

This will fail to compile if you use features that pointers to `T` do not support. By using features of `A` I think it should be guaranteed that pointers to `B` and `C` will also work as expected. However, it would be possible to call this function with vectors of `D *`, provided `D`'s interface complies with what `my_function` tries to do.